# Paypal discount and coupon in android

Tags: android, paypal

Is there any way or alternative in implementing discounts and coupons in android?

There's no problem when using discount per item because i deducted the item total before adding to PaypalItem but i got a great problem when adding discount per subtotal or transaction.

Best Regards!